# How to add product variation to a link?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make it so that when I share a link of a product with a quantity attribute the person who opens it sees it with the exact quantity. Is there a plugin for that? (woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your question is not clear, if I understand correctly you need to do something like this:

```
https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=[the product id]&quantity=[quantity to add to cart]
```

For example:

```
https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=72&quantity=3
```

Comment: No, sorry for not making it more clear but I am trying to do something like this https://yourdomain.com/product/product_name/?quantity=1000

Comment: Do you want to link a product and pre-fill the quantity field from the url?

Comment: Yes, that would work! Can you help, please!